# Using MongoDB and storing critical information so that it is protected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose

I am using mongoose with MongoDB in a NodeJS application. Right now, in development, I have a configuration (.env) file which stores sensitive information my code needs to run. For example, the MongoDB password & URL, emails & passwords needed to email using the code, etc.

When I put it into production, it would obviously be wrong to upload this configuration file anywhere on the cloud, given the information in it. How can I make it so my production code, hosted somewhere such as Heroku, can access these needed variables without letting undue access to them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, pushing your `env` file to production is pretty bad from a security perspective.

The way you would go with storing your environmental variables differs between cloud platforms, but essentially you should get a secure way of adding them through either an user interface or through terminal (You usually find these information easily by looking into your provider documentation).

To store them in a project deployed on Heroku, you will need to:

1. Log to Heroku
2. Open the newly deployed project
3. Head over the `Settings` tab
4. Find the section named `Config Vars`
5. Click on `Reveal Vars`
6. Add your variables in there

And you are good to go!

Comment: Than you! Is this feature available on most hosting sites (for NodeJS)?

Comment: Essentially yes, as you most likely will always need to set variables for your project - But some providers may allow you to do it differently (e.g. With AWS you'd do it through terminal instead)